# Print all filenames in a folder in iOS application

Tags: ios, file, swift, nsfilemanager

I have a folder with 4 subfolders in my iOS application with each of these containing about 20 files each. I would like to be able to iterate through each folder and print out the filenames. I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Here is what I have tried:

```
    let docsPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath! + "/Samples";
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    var error: NSError?
    let docsArray = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(docsPath, error:&error)
    println(docsArray)
```

This prints out nil. I expect it to print out each of the filenames. How do I make this happen?

Comment: do "`println(\error.localizedDescription)`" and tell me what error you are getting...

Comment: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)"

Comment: where is your Sample folder located ?

Comment: In the main project folder

Comment: In Xcode, is the "Samples" folder blue or yellow? If it's not blue, its contents will end up in the root of your app bundle and your app won't actually have a "Samples" folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here:

1)

Check your built app to see if "Samples" is really ending up in the built binary.  From the error of "The operation couldn’t be completed", I'm thinking you aren't copying "Samples" into the compiled app bundle or at least into the place you're expecting it to be.

2)

The call you're doing will give you the contents of the folder, but ***not*** the contents of the subfolders which is what you really want to list.

Use [`NSDirectoryEnumerator`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDirectoryEnumerator_Class/index.html) instead to get the contents of that folder and subfolders.  [Here is a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943392/how-to-optimize-directory-listing-enumeratoratpath-and-recursive-call-contents) that might give you one direction to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NSFileManager's enumerator if you want to get all the files including inside subdirectories.

Simple example:

```
if let enumerator = fileManager.enumeratorAtURL(docsPath, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: nil, errorHandler: nil) {
    while let url = enumerator.nextObject() as? NSURL {
        println(url)
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not have to use the `enumeratorAtURL` function. The `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath` function is just fine.

Comment: `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath` does not traverse subdirectories, this one does; I've edited my answer with this info.

Comment: True. It depends on what the OP needs. But since they are getting `nil`, it most likely means the path isn't valid so using `enumeratorAtURL` won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out:

```
    var docsPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath! + "/Snare";
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    var error: NSError?
    let docsArray = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(docsPath, error:&error)

    //println(error!.localizedDescription)
    println(docsArray)


    for filename in docsArray!
    {
        let subfolderPath = docsPath + "/"+(filename as! String)
        println(docsPath)

        let subarray = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(subfolderPath, error: &error)
        println(subarray)
    }
```

Comment: So it was simply a typo in the pathname.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW38

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingPathComponent: