# Can someone explain what URLResourceKeys are?

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager

I was looking at the documentation for [`contentsOfDirectory(at:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1413768-contentsofdirectory)

Particularly I've been focusing on the argument `includingPropertiesForKeys`, which said:

> An array of keys that identify the file properties that you want pre-fetched for each item in the directory. For each returned URL, the specified properties are fetched and cached in the NSURL object. For a list of keys you can specify, see Common File System Resource Keys.

Clicking on [URLResourceKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlresourcekey) led me to the Apple Documentation about it.

And I was wondering, if I passed in keys like `fileResourceTypeKey`, `fileResourceIdentifierKey`, and `creationDateKey` how could  I access those in the returned URL list (after calling `contentsOfDirectory(at:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:)`)?

And I was also confused by the `URLResourceKey` enum b/c a lot of types have similar descriptions and names to other keys like:

- `documentIdentifierKey` vs `fileResourceIdentifierKey`vs `localizedNameKey` vs `nameKey`
- `localizedTypeDescriptionKey` vs `fileResourceTypeKey` vs `typeIdentifierKey`
- the urls returned by the `contentsOfDirectory(at:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:)` vs `pathKey`

Like what would be the differences between these keys?

Basically I have a really low understanding of the file system at this point so please bear with my "simple" questions. If someone could explain what all these keys means and how I can access/use them that would be great!

Comment: Please search before asking. Good example (from vadian!) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41979314/341994

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all the [URLResourceKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlresourcekey) documentation describes the kind of the attribute information very well. For example `nameKey` returns always `Desktop` for an URL representing `~/Desktop` while `localizedNameKey` returns the localized name `Schreibtisch` on a German system or `Bureau` on a French system. However `documentIdentifierKey` and `fileResourceIdentifierKey` are completely different attributes.

---

Regarding the `contentsOfDirectory(at:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:)` API: The keys passed in the `includingPropertiesForKeys` parameter tells the framework to pre-fetch the corresponding attributes while getting the contents for performance reasons. For example

```
let contentURLs = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: anURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: [.nameKey, .fileSizeKey], options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
```

To read the attributes call `resourceValues(forKeys` on the URL passing the same keys as in `contentsOfDirectory`. Then get the value with the corresponding property of the resource key. The benefit of the combination `URLResourceKey / URLResourceValues` is you get always the proper type from the file attributes. This avoids any type casting.

```
for fileURL in contentURLs {
     do {
        let fileAttributes = try fileURL.resourceValues(forKeys:[.nameKey, .fileSizeKey])
        print(fileAttributes.name!) // is String
        print(fileAttributes.fileSize!) // is Int
     } catch { print(error, fileURL) }
}
```