# get real file path with swift with whitespace

Tags: swift

I have been trying to work with files and folders using swift

I'm using code from [listing all files in a folder recursively with swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57640119/listing-all-files-in-a-folder-recursively-with-swift#57640445)

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/to/directory")
var files = [URL]()
if let enumerator = FileManager.default.enumerator(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: [.isRegularFileKey], options: [.skipsHiddenFiles, .skipsPackageDescendants]) {
    for case let fileURL as URL in enumerator {
        do {
            let fileAttributes = try fileURL.resourceValues(forKeys:[.isRegularFileKey])
            if fileAttributes.isRegularFile! {
                files.append(fileURL)
            }
        } catch { 
            print(error, fileURL) 
        }
    }
    print(files)
}
```

It works fine when printing list of files, but the result contains file:/// prefix and if file path or file name contains a white space, the result will add "%20", this is causing some issues

for example: file $_59 (7).jpeg, from above code, the path is `file:///Users/kkkk/folder/$_59%20(7).jpeg`

when reading it

```
let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
```

got error: `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “$_59%20(7).jpeg” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."`

I removed prefix `file://` so now the path I get is /Users/kkkk/folder/$_59%20(7).jpeg,

As I test, I found that it works if I manually enter /Users/kkkk/folder/$_59 (7).jpeg

So any idea how i can get real path /Users/kkkk/folder/$_59 (7).jpeg?

Comment: Please edit your question and show how you are getting a string from your URL. Note that you should work with URL instead of paths. Btw looks like you are using the URL `.absoluteString` (includes the URL schema "file://") when you should be using its `.path` property.

Comment: .path, that's why.....thx for pointing out, please edit ur answer so that I can mark it accepted

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40642217/uiimagecontentsoffile-returning-nil-despite-file-existing-in-caches-directory/40643037