# FileManager can't locate PDF directory in Xcode project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to list all PDFs inside a folder that is stored in my Xcode project using SwiftUI, but after trying many different methods I found on here I cannot get it working.

Currently I am using file manager to list the items but when I try and print or list the items found it returns `nil`.

I have added the PDFs by dragging them into the Xcode project. I have also made sure that they are in my **Copy Bundle Resource** so I can use FileManager. See below:

[image]

Here is my Xcode structure, I am trying to list all items inside `PDF`. As you can see below the PDFs are stored outside the main folder structure in **"/Swift/Products/Detail/Tab5/PDF"**, so when trying to list the files using    `Bundle.main.bundlePath`, it looks at `products.app`.

[image]

Here is the code where I am trying to use FileManager to find all PDFs inside the folder:

```
struct ProductTab5View: View {
    
    @State var files = getFiles()

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(0..<files.count, id: \.self) { item in
                 Text(files[item])
             }
        }
    }
}

func getFiles() -> Array<String>{
    // Get  document directory url
    let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    var files: [String] = []
    
    do {
        // Get the directory contents urls (including subfolders urls)
        let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
        print(directoryContents)
        // filter  directory contents:
        let pdfFiles = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "pdf" }
        let pdfFileNames = pdfFiles.map{ $0.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent }
        files.append(contentsOf: pdfFileNames)

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    return files
}
```

Comment: Please add a screenshot of where that pdf file is located in final built application bundle.

Comment: @Asperi I have updated the post showing the bundle resources. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such a way resources are copied flat into root application bundle, not user 's `Documents` as it was tried in provided code snapshot (and no `PDF` sub-directory is created for you).

So the solution would be just to iterate internal pdf files, like

```
func getFiles() -> Array<String> {
    return Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "pdf", subdirectory: nil)?
        .compactMap { $0.lastPathComponent } ?? []
}
```

Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

Answer (score 1):

There are a few potential problems with your current code.

The first is this line:

```
FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
```

Unless you have gone through a process separately from what you've shown of adding all of these files to the app's document directory, then there's no reason to believe that these files will be there.  In other words: your Xcode project is *not* the same as your app's document directory.  Think of the app's document directory as a place where you may store user-created or perhaps downloaded content as managed by the app -- not Xcode itself.

Next thing to check is whether all of these files are truly added to your target.  Check your target's "Build Phases" -> "Copy Bundle Resources" section to see if they appear there.

If they do, you *can* use FileManager, but you have to access the correct directory, which is inside the main bundle -- not the app's user document directory.

The following answer goes into details about this (**including making sure you create folder references**): [Getting a list of files in the Resources folder - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398937/getting-a-list-of-files-in-the-resources-folder-ios)

The gist will be doing something like this:

```
if let files = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: Bundle.main.bundlePath) { //may need to dig into subdirectories
   for file in files {
            //manipulate the file
        }
    }
```

and then using FileManager to list the documents in that path.

Note that you can also get all the files (including subdirectories) recursively by doing something like this:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.bundlePath)
if let enumerator = FileManager.default.enumerator(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: [.isRegularFileKey], options: [.skipsHiddenFiles, .skipsPackageDescendants]) {
    for case let fileURL as URL in enumerator {
        print(fileURL)
    }
}
```

By using the above code during your debugging process, this should give you an insight into what your directory structure is really like inside your bundle.  Once you've figured that out, adjust the previous code sample to be something like:

```
if let files = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: Bundle.main.bundlePath + mySubPath) {
   for file in files {
            //manipulate the file
        }
    }
```

which will give you just the files in the one subdirectory you want once you fill in `mySubPath`.  Note that if you want recursive search, you can use the code sample above.

You may want to exclude non-file items eventually -- see this answer for more details about recursive directory lists in Swift: [listing all files in a folder recursively with swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57640119/listing-all-files-in-a-folder-recursively-with-swift)

Comment: Thanks @jn_pdx. I have manually added these files into the app's document directory. After checking the Bundle Resources I can see the pdf is in there. Could you update the link as it doesn't seem to work please? Hopefully that will answer my question.

Comment: Thank you for the link but I am really struggling to get my head around this. How do I dig into subdirectories? If I run your code it does return the PDF folder but also a bunch of other stuff in the bundle `Info.plist` for example.

Comment: Just append your PDF directory name. FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: Bundle.main.bundlePath + "/PDF") or whatever it is

Comment: I suggest you print(Bundle.main.bundlePath) so you can see what it's giving you -- then you can explore that directory in Finder or the terminal (assuming you're running on a Mac or the simulator) and see how you would need to append more information to that string to get to the right subdirectory

Comment: Thanks, when I print(Bundle.main.bundlePath) it points me to `Products.app` which is the name of my app (as you can see from my hierarchy in the original post. If I add `+ "/Swift/PDF"` that will give me a non-existent path, I know I am probably making this more difficult than it is but surely there is an easy way to list all files inside a folder directory.

Comment: In finder, right click your products.app and select “show package contents”. You can explore the directory structure there. Or, you can look at the list provided by the sample code I already have you and see what your sub directory options are.

Comment: Added to my answer including recursive search options