# How to Use Recursion to get all Files in a Directory Tree for Firebase Cloud Storage

Tags: swift, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I've been playing around with Firebase Cloud Storage lately in Swift, and I've come across a scenario where I would like to retrieve images (and only images) in a "folder" (that has other sub folders in it) stored in the bucket. In other words, I want to use recursion to access the files nested in many folders.

I've seen examples done such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57640119/listing-all-files-in-a-folder-recursively-with-swift), but of course, this is by using Swift's `FileManager`, so I won't be able to utilize the same feature on Firebase Cloud Storage.

Also, keep in mind that I don't want to have a hard-coded reference path such as `storage.reference().child("Hard-coded path")`

This is what I have so far without using recursion:

```
class FIRQueries {
    var storage: Storage
    var storageRef: StorageReference
    init() {
        storage = Storage.storage()
        storageRef = storage.reference()
    }
    func listFilesInCloud(completion: @escaping(Result<StorageListResult, Error>) -> ()) {
        self.storageRef.root().listAll { result, error in
        if let error = error {
            completion(.failure(error))
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        } else {
            completion(.success(result))
            for prefix in result.prefixes {
                completion(.success(prefix.fullPath))
            }
            for item in result.items {
                print(item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and receiving the results in a SwiftUI `.onAppear` block

```
.onAppear {
        FIRQueries().listFilesInCloud { value in
            switch value {
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                
            case .success(let result):
                for prefix in result.prefixes {
                    print(prefix.fullPath)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Soo... is there any way to achieve this? With this code, I've only managed to get the names of the "folder" under the root of the bucket. I know I can set a `child` after `self.storageRef.root()` and give it a path, but then it'll be a hard-coded path.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Firebase documentation on [listing all files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/list-files#list_all_files) shows, you can call `listAll(completion:)` on each prefix to recursively.

So:

```
for prefix in result.prefixes {
    print(prefix.fullPath)
    prefix.listAll(...) //  List files in subdirectory
}
```